# Mutate a vector within a pipe chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to subtract 1 from a vector within a pipe chain. Example, `mtcars$mpg`.

```
x <- mtcars
# I don't want to do this:
x %>% mutate(mpg = mpg - 1)
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
x$mpg %>% mutate(. := .-1)
```

If what I wrote there isn't clear in the second block, I'm trying to write, "take mpg vector then mutate it to be mpg - 1"

Is this possible?

Comment: With `pipe`, you can do `library(magrittr);x$mpg %>% subtract(1)` or `x$mpg %>% {. -1}`.  The `tidyverse` functions `mutate/summarise` expects a data.frame/tbl_df and not a vector.  I am not sure about the use case for this

Comment: Or `x$mpg %>% \`-\`(-1)`

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen single curly braces before. How should I read those?

Comment: It is for blocking the code just like in a `for` loop `for(i in 1:5) {print(i); do something}`

Comment: If you want it to update as well `x$mpg %>% {. -1} -> x$mpg`

Comment: OK, confirming there's no comma in there? `{. -1}` not `{., -1}`?

Comment: No, because the `.` is the column values of `mpg` as a vector on which the subtraction happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutate/summarise` and other tidyverse functions expects a `data.frame` as `.data`.   As we are extracting the column values, either use the `magrittr` helper function `subtract`

```
library(magrittr)
x$mpg %>%
     subtract(1)
```

Or block the code in a `{}` and then update the column

```
x$mpg %>%
      {. -1} -> x$mpg
```

Or use the compound assignment operator (`%<>%`) for updating the column

```
head(x$mpg)
#[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1

x$mpg %<>%
          {.- 1}
head(x$mpg)
#[1] 20.0 20.0 21.8 20.4 17.7 17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `"-"(1)` after `%>%`